# TYPO3 Scheduler task: Remove a record from a corresponding repository (->repository methods)

Tags: php, typo3, task

I've developed a Scheduler task in TYPO3 which basically generates files while accessing each class repository. If a certain record, which has a dependency with a record of another class is being deleted in the BE i want the task to also remove this corresponding record from the repository as well. For that i thought of using repository methods.

Here i define the repositories (there are more, but those two are relevant for my problem):

```
/** @var CustomerRepository $apprep */
$apprep = $objectManager->get(\Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Repository\HostRepository::class);
/** @var Typo3QuerySettings $querySettings */
$querySettings = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
$querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
$apprep->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
$hosts = $apprep->findAll();

/** @var CustomerRepository $apprep2 */
$apprep2 = $objectManager->get(\Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Repository\ServicesRepository::class);
/** @var Typo3QuerySettings $querySettings */
$querySettings = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
$querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
$apprep2->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
$services = $apprep2->findAll();
$srvrep = $apprep2;
```

Farther down in my code i have the following block:

```
foreach($services as $service){   
    $validate2 = false;
    foreach($hosts as $host){
        if($host->getUid() == $service->getHost()){
            $validate2 = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($validate2 == false){
        foreach($kunden as $kunde){
            $name = $kunde->getName();
            $files = array_filter(scandir('/etc/icinga2/conf.d/hosts/'.$name.'/'), function($item) {
            return !is_dir('/etc/icinga2/conf.d/hosts/'.$name.'/'. $item);
            }); 
            foreach($files as $fileval){
                if($fileval == 'Service_' . $service->getServicename(). '_'. $kunde->getKundennummer().'.conf'){
                    unlink('/etc/icinga2/conf.d/hosts/'.$kunde->getName().'/'.$fileval);
                }
            }
        }
        $srvrep->remove($service);
    }
}
```

So as you can see, i check if a corresponding service has any host (the getter getHost() of the $service object returns basically the Uid of the specific corresponding host object (getUid()) if there is a dependency. If there is no dependency it first removes the file and then i want it to remove the record from the repository. but the line

```
$srvrep->remove($service);
```

Doesn't seem to work as i want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the Extbase persistence layer in any context besides an Extbase `ActionController`, you need to manually flush the `PersistenceManager` to persist your changes.

```php
$persistenceManager = $objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager::class);
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i needed.